# Django query across foreign keys to a filtered query set

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model set like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class CarModel(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I get a query set with all the categories of cars owned by the current user?

Thanks!
T

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read examples in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships ?

Comment: The queries doc page doesn't seem to have two deep foreign key example and, interestingly, doesn't reference .values().  After Fazil's post, I found this link helpful: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user).select_related('car_model__category').all()
```

Comment: Sweet!  I added the .distinct() to get what I was looking for.    Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('car_model__category__name').distinct()

Comment: Or it could be done with `value_list`, @Tsmith `Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values_list('car_model__category__name', flat=True)`

Comment: After using this a bit, it is't quite what I'm looking for.  This returns the correct list, but as dictionary (.values) or list (.values_list).  I want the objects. Using select_related joins the tables, but I don't want that.  I want the set of categories filtered by the cars that relate back to them.

Comment: I was able to do this in two steps.  `ql = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values_list('car_mode‌​l__category').distinct()` followed by
`qs = Category.objects.filter(id__in=ql))`.  But I would think there is a better way.